# How to display video in react js using jsx tags

Tags: html, reactjs, video, jsx

Hello i am working on react js project and tailwind for the css i have a list of cards where i want to display a video instead of image in every card . The video should be played when i hover on the card but before getting to that i can't figure out how to display the vidéo in the card i've been searching on internet and this is the solution i found but it doesn't display anything.

```
     <video className={`object-cover w-full h-full rounded border-4 border-solid `} >
        <source
          src={`/../../assets/videos/video.mp4`}
          type="video/mp4"
          className={`object-cover w-full h-full rounded border-4 border-solid `}
        />
      </video>
```

i tried to use require in the src , i tried to import the video and then put src={video} in the source tag i removed the / in the beginnig of the path but none of these solutions worked for me . So any help please ?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong here. You might post the rendered HTML. That may reveal issues.

Answer (score 0):

well you can not access any asset or component out of your src folder.
try to move the video inside the src folder.